# Pivot Table Error | Invalid Call or Procedure

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need some help with this one. I am trying to create a pivot table, starting in Q1, of a range of data in the same sheet. The first if-statement is there because the last column doesn't always contain a header, so I include it there.

I want the range to be dynamic since the size of the tables being made will vary depending on the number of rows of the data in the sheet. The source data is always A1:O & lastRow and the table always needs to be placed in Q1 of the same sheet.

I am getting an error - "Invalid call or procedure" - screenshot below.

The issue line when debugging is where I set the pivot table - also in screenshot below.

If it helps, I am running this code from a separate sheet in a start-up folder.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

***UPDATED TO SHOW CURRENT CODE USING COMMENT SUGGESTIONS***

```
Sub aaTemp()
'
' aaTemp Macro
'

If Range("O1").Value = "" Then
    Range("O1").Value = "Notes"
    Else
    End If

Dim lastRow, lastColumn As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).row
    lastColumn = 15

'Dim pivotSource As String
    'pivotSource = "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("A1:O" & lastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Dim pivotDestination As String
    'pivotDestination = "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("Q1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    sourceData:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O" & lastRow), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Columns("Q:Z").delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, _
    TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q1"), _
    TableName:="PTPivotTable")

End Sub
```

[image: Error Code]

[image: Highlighted Issue in Script]

Comment: Your code works in the first run! The error comes with the 2nd run! => delete the pivot destination range! (e.g. `Columns("Q:Z").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft` prior to `Set pt = ws.PivotTables ...`)

Comment: If any of your sheet names might contain spaces then you need to add single quotes when constructing the range address -  e.g. `pivotDestination = "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & ...`    You should just assign the range directly though - no need for constructing a String address: `sourceData:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O" & lastRow)`

Comment: So I tried deleting the comments prior to "set pt" as simple-solution recommended and the code comes with the same error.

Comment: I also tried constructing addresses w/o the string variable and still the same error

```

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    sourceData:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O" & lastRow), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Columns("Q:Z").delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, _
    TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q1"), _
    TableName:="PTPivotTable")

End Sub

Comment: I updated the original post to show the current code with these two suggestions. Same error.

Comment: Change `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` to `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @Rory That was the answer to the riddle. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub aaTemp()
'
' aaTemp Macro
'

If Range("O1").Value = "" Then
    Range("O1").Value = "Notes"
    Else
    End If

Dim lastRow, lastColumn As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).row
    lastColumn = 15

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook   'This was the needed change

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    sourceData:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O" & lastRow), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Columns("Q:Z").delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, _
    TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q1"), _
    TableName:="PTPivotTable")

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).